# How to display HTML entities on page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an HTML entity to display to the page without showing up as the symbol it represents. EX: I want to have &#60 show up on the screen instead of <. I am doing this inside of a code window that I created on my page to show how HTML entities are used in the code itself. Is there a way that I can do this in HTML and if so how would I go about doing this?

`<pre> <code> &#60 </code> </pre>`

Comment: so like `&amp;#60`